# java JDBC MYSQL Syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Well, I have got some problems with this sql syntax.

```
public static void newTable(String tableName, String columnName, String columnType) {

    try {

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement
                ("CREATE TABLE `" + tableName + "`" + "(`" +columnName + "`  `" +  columnType + "` )");

        //PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE teszt2 ( asd VARCHAR(255) );" ); //THIS IS WORKING

        //pst.setString(1, tableName);
        //pst.setString(2, columnName);
        //pst.setString(3, columnType);
        pst.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the error that I got:
Every time I run this I got this error. I assume that I have some problems with my query.
Although, the one without strings in it is working fine.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`VARCHAR(255)` )' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments in your code, this works:

```
CREATE TABLE teszt2 ( asd VARCHAR(255) );
```

But this doesn't:

```
CREATE TABLE `teszt2` ( `asd` `VARCHAR(255)` );
```

So I guess remove the back-ticks and use the "working" version:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement
            ("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (" +columnName + " " +  columnType + " )");
```

Or at least remove them from the type specifier:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement
            ("CREATE TABLE `" + tableName + "`" + "(`" +columnName + "`  " +  columnType + " )");
```

Comment: THANKS for the fast answer. I don't know how could I be this stupid.
I removed the back-ticks from the type specifier and it works like a charm. :) Thank you, again.